# Javascript: How to access element based on input parameter?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Framework: Javascript, Jqgrid

I have the below javascript function. It receives array of fields and Jqgrid. It sets the fields's required attribute to true. I want to pass an input string 'Required' and let the function set the element 'Required' to true. This way, I can reuse this function to set 'Integer', 'Email' attributes etc. I am looking for a feature similar to Java's reflection in Javascript. Can you please guide me if there is a way in Javascript to do that?

```
        function setRequiredFields(fields, grid){
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var colProp = $(grid).getColProp(fields[i]);                
            getColPropEditRules(colProp).Required = true;
            getColPropFormOptions(colProp).elmsuffix = " *";                
            $(grid).setColProp(fields[i], colProp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is more jqGrid issue than JavaScript, added the relevant tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you need is "array" syntax:

```
function setRequiredFields(fields, grid, propertyName){
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var colProp = $(grid).getColProp(fields[i]);                
        getColPropEditRules(colProp) [propertyName] = true;
        getColPropFormOptions(colProp).elmsuffix = " *";                
        $(grid).setColProp(fields[i], colProp);
    }
}
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The corrected version of the function which you need can be

```
function setRequiredFields(fields, grid) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var colProp = $(grid).jqGrid('getColProp',fields[i]);
        if (typeof colProp.editrules === "undefined") {
            colProp.editrules = {};
        }
        colProp.editrules.required = true;
        if (typeof colProp.formoptions === "undefined") {
            colProp.formoptions = {};
        }
        colProp.formoptions.elmsuffix = " *";
    }
}
```

Probably you can additionally reduce `$(grid)` to `grid`.

Small comments about the changes. The `required` property of the [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) should be correct written without capital characters. Moreover the method `getColProp` return the reference to the corresponding `colModel` element so you need not use `setColProp` additionally.

Comment: Thanks! @Oleg for improving my function. It really helped me to optimize my code. Thanks! a lot.